# C function to capitalize the first character of a pointer string

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to capitalize the first character of a pointer string.

For example, input: john 
Output: John

I can do it with arrays `(s[0] = toUpper(s[0])`, but is there a way to do it with pointers?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 30

int transform(char *s)

{
    while (*s != '\0')
    {
        *s = toupper(*s); 
        s++;
    }

    return *s;
}

int main()
{
    printf("String: ");
    char *s[MAX];


    getline(&s,MAX);

    transform(s);
    printf("Transformed char: %s", &s);

}

int getline(char *s, int lim) 
{
    int c;
    char *t=s;
    while (--lim>0 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n') *s++=c;
    *s='\0';
    while (c!=EOF && c!='\n')
        c=getchar();
    return s-t;
}
```

This code turns the whole string to upper case.

Comment: Why are you looping through a pointer to a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `transform` function is looping through the entire string and running `toupper` on each one.  Just run it on the first character:

```
void transform(char *s)
{
    *s = toupper(*s); 
}
```

Also, you declare `s` in `main` as an array of pointers to `char`.  You just want an array of `char`:

```
int main()
{
    printf("String: ");
    char s[MAX];


    getline(s,MAX);      // don't take the address of s here

    transform(s);
    printf("Transformed char: %s", s);    // or here

}
```

You want to move `main` to the end of the file as well, so that `getline` is defined before it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:

```
void transform(char* p) {
    //Only first character
    *p = toupper(*p);
}

//Call like that:
char str[] = "test";
transform(str); //str becomes: "Test"
```